# Something wrong in my project, using fabric.js

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

```
function loadimg(src){
        var newww=new fabric.Image.fromURL(src,function(img){
            window.canvas.centerObject(img);
            window.canvas.setActiveObject(img);
            window.canvas.add(img);
        },{
            H_PADDING: 20,
            V_PADDING: 50,
        });

    // window.canvas_obj.add(neww);
    add_layer(src);
}
```

that is my package function to load an image to the canvas and I want to select the image object that was put into canvas by the API  `canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(i))`
but it only finds the `item(0)`, 1, 2, 3. Once more, it can't find it.

Comment: hard to understand what is your problem. can you provide a fiddle with this code running?

Answer (score 0):

what you need  is to load an image and make it active ?

If so,   i created a jsfiddle example that loads an image and activates it.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

var site_url =  'http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg';

//i use loadSVGFromURL to load an svg image but it is the same if you would like to use fabric.Image.fromURL() to load your image
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(site_url, function(obj) { 
          var img = new fabric.PathGroup(obj, { 
          left: 165, 
          top: 100, 
          width: 295, 
          height: 211 
        }); 
//add the loaded image on the canvas
        canvas.add(img); 
//activate(select) the image
    canvas.setActiveObject(img);
//render canvas to show the borders on the image
        canvas.renderAll(); 
          });
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/v4qzuw9w/

hope helps ,good luck.